# Learn Python the hard way Exercise 35: Can't understand how it's connected

Tags: python

I understand what the different blocks do, but I can't understand how are they connected or what tells Python where to start. Could anyone clarify? Thanks!

```
from sys import exit

def gold_room():
    print "This room is full of gold.  How much do you take?"

    next = raw_input("> ")
    if "0" in next or "1" in next:
        how_much = int(next)
    else:
        dead("Man, learn to type a number.")

    if how_much < 50:
        print "Nice, you're not greedy, you win!"
        exit(0)
    else:
        dead("You greedy bastard!")


def bear_room():
    print "There is a bear here."
    print "The bear has a bunch of honey."
    print "The fat bear is in front of another door."
    print "How are you going to move the bear?"
    bear_moved = False

    while True:
        next = raw_input("> ")

        if next == "take honey":
            dead("The bear looks at you then slaps your face off.")
        elif next == "taunt bear" and not bear_moved:
            print "The bear has moved from the door. You can go through it now."
            bear_moved = True
        elif next == "taunt bear" and bear_moved:
            dead("The bear gets pissed off and chews your leg off.")
        elif next == "open door" and bear_moved:
            gold_room()
        else:
            print "I got no idea what that means."


def cthulhu_room():
    print "Here you see the great evil Cthulhu."
    print "He, it, whatever stares at you and you go insane."
    print "Do you flee for your life or eat your head?"

    next = raw_input("> ")

    if "flee" in next:
        start()
    elif "head" in next:
        dead("Well that was tasty!")
    else:
        cthulhu_room()


def dead(why):
    print why, "Good job!"
    exit(0)

def start():
    print "You are in a dark room."
    print "There is a door to your right and left."
    print "Which one do you take?"

    next = raw_input("> ")

    if next == "left":
        bear_room()
    elif next == "right":
        cthulhu_room()
    else:
        dead("You stumble around the room until you starve.")


start()
```

Comment: Which do you want to understand more clearly? All of these snippets?

Comment: The various blocks are defining functions. The 'start()' call at the end calls the 'start' function defined just above. Inside that function it calls the bear_room and cthulhu_room functions.

Comment: Be forgiving. Newbies won't know what's important information for others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you make a car, you have a car, but it doesn't drive away. When you define a function, it creates a new function, but doesn't execute it.

All of those "def" statements just add new verbs to your space. It's only when one is called (`start()`) that something starts happening.

Comment: Yes, I see it now, no function is called until the very end when start() gets called, i got confused with the code, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Python evaluates the file. The functions are defined with `def`.

Then it reaches an expression at the end of the file, `start()`. This means "call the `start` function".

The start function then calls other functions, such as `bear_room()`, etc.